# Which session file is read when accessing session data in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, session

in laravel/storeage/framework/sessions, there are many session files. When using a key to access session data as
`session('keyID')`, how does it work?
Which session file is read to find the key? Or all the files will be searched?

Answer (score 1):

The files are named in a way to be the identifier. The session cookie that you send with each request has that identifier in it. So it can match those up. In the file that is just serialized data.